# What is the purpose of allocator_traits<T> in C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, traits, allocator

Why isn't standard C++03 interface for querying member types for allocators used in C++0x? What are the use cases where member types are not sufficient?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this kind of things (*at all*), but [this document](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2946.pdf) seems like a good starting point to get a grasp on the rationale behind `allocator_traits` :

> The keystone of this proposal is the
>   definition of an `allocator_traits`
>   template containing  types and static
>   member functions for using allocators,
>   **effectively replacing the `Allocator` concept that was lost in
>   Frankfurt**.

Comment: Seems rather dumb to do `auto p = allocator_traits<Alloc>::allocate(myalloc, n);`
instead of
`auto p = myalloc.allocate(n);` since the former is eventually calling the latter. Why did they add the former interface at all?

Comment: @buratinas: in my understanding, to support the [Scoped Allocator Model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf)

Answer (score 12):

To explain allocator_traits in terms of design pattern, its an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to wrap your custom Allocator that meets far less implementation requirement (no need for construct, destroy, all those typedefs ...) and turns it into [FlyWeight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) object that completes the rest of the Allocator implementation requirement for you with static members and types.

With allocator_traits, you just need to provide minimum of 10 lines of code for your custom allocator, as per page 3 of open-std doc [Scoped Allocator Model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf) (thx to @icecrime for mentioning).

I think of allocator_traits and allocator as a nice real-world example of turning non-FlyWeight object into FlyWeight in order to relieve the burden of implementaion details. Its a good API design practice for turning a class into FlyWeight that should've been FlyWeight in the first place.

To Java Programmers, in terms of design pattern, std::allocator_traits is like package private classes CharacterDataLatin1, ChracterData00, CharacterData0E, 01, 02 ... that inherits from java.lang.CharacterData to provide static Unicode definition and helpers that are to be shared by every instance of Character (std::allocator) classes.

**Edit**:
Another advantage of indirectly calling your custom allocator through allocator_traits is that it guarantees foward compatibility (page 3 of [Scoped Allocator Model](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2554.pdf)).
Number of [requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) may grow in the future, and even if your ignorant on implementing new requirements to your allocator, those requirements will already be there in allocator_traits implemented by the compiler manufacturer. Knowing that C++ containers call allocator indirectly by allocator_traits, the STL containers using your custom allocator will be benefiting from the new requirements without the need for you to change your code.

Comment: Confused what this has to do with the flyweight pattern. Isn't that about reducing memory usage? Also, couldn't they just tell people to inherit from `std::allocator`...?

Comment: @user541686: you have to abstrarct away the flywheight pattern and apply it to the language modeled by type computations occuring at the time template instantiations. In this model, the objects in the domain of discourse are actually types, and each instantiation context is a distinct (template) meta program who's output is the requested template specialization. Since the objects in this model are c++ types, and since most of allocator would define their nested types are defined in a similar fashion, then `allocator_traits<A>` acts as a flyweight obkect over a single set of defaut types.